# how to generate a readable name in a SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

In a stored procedure, I would like to generate a 'name' field in order to populate a dummy data table.
I use this and it works:

```
SET @nom = CONV(FLOOR(RAND() * 99999999999999), 20, 36);
```

But since this is for a name field, I would like to have only letters and not a mixture of letters and numbers.
I wanted to try something like this, but it doesn't work

```
  SET @lenght=8+rand() *10; -- Définit une longueur aléatoire compris entre 8 et 18 caractères
  SET@nom='';
  WHILE @lenght>0 DO
     @nom = CONCAT(@nom, char(round(rand()*25+65,0)));
     SET @lenght=@lenght -1;
  END WHILE;
```

do you have an idea?
Array-type variables cannot be used?
I could have taken a random character in an array variable on each iteration of the loop

```
SET @vowel= ('a','e','i', 'o','u','y');
```

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server !!! Select one of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION generate_random_word (len TINYINT UNSIGNED)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
DECLARE result VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    REPEAT
        SET result = CONCAT(result, CHAR(CEIL(RAND()*26+64)));
        SET len = len - 1;
    UNTIL !len END REPEAT;
RETURN result;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2732456d0d418b1b181a4352c534119

Comment: thank you, it works. It comes close to my solution which was not working. suddenly I understand even less what was wrong with mine. Do you know if we can use array type variables at once?

Comment: I mixed the 2
`code
 SET @lenght=8+rand() *10;
        SET @nom='';
 REPEAT
           SET @nom = CONCAT(@nom, CHAR(CEIL(RAND()*26+64)));
           SET @lenght = @lenght - 1;
  UNTIL @lenght<1 END REPEAT; `